# How to separate house number from full address using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching address from all over the world and format for the address is different. What I need is to separate house number from rest of the address and return house number as a separate element and rest of the address as a separate using JavaScript or jQuery.
Here is example of address:

```
Langstrasse 120, Zürich
1314 Grant Street, San Francisco
```

Comment: you may want to use split() method

Comment: Split method will work if house number if either of one side.

Comment: Step 1: invent AI capable of interpreting ambiguous input.   Seriously, this is an impossible task: consider "123 5th Avenue" or "123 Avenida 12 de Octubre".  Splitting the string based on digits is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
var addr = 'Langstrasse 120, Zürich';
var myA = addr.split(/(\d+)/g);
```

This will give you the House number from the Address and then replace this number with whole address, You will find the address without house number.

```
var full_address    = addr.replace(myA[1],"");
```

your `myA[1]` will be house number and `full_address` will be address without House number.

Comment: Bingo!! this is working like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var address = 'Langstrasse 120, Zürich';
var matches = address.match('![0-9/-]+!');
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: what about JS....?

Comment: sorry forgot it was JS you are asking :D

Comment: What are the `!`s for? AFAIK they have no special meaning in regex, so they're being interpreted literally.

Comment: will this work from second address?